# how I save the incoming text messages into an string ArrayList in android?

Tags: arraylist

how I save the incoming text messages into an string ArrayList in android? i get the sms into a broadcastreceiver class and want to put those text messages to a string ArrayList,every time the message receive put into an ArrayList's next index.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to get the information down to what ever string representation that you are interested in, what is stopping you from using a normal java arraylist in android?

```
 String test = "test";
 List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
 list.add(test);

 for(String s:list) {
     System.out.println(s);
 }
```